# How to disable dependent picklist field on page load?

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, visualforce-component

I have 3 picklist fields on Visualforce page. Lead source, lead source Type, lead source status. lead source status dependent on lead source Type and lead source Type dependent on  Lead source.
On page load, how to disable this 2 field:- lead source Type, lead source status.
I want to show only Lead source field on page VF Page load.

Comment: Do you want to disable it or to hide it?

Comment: I want to disable the fields  on VF Page.

Comment: Do you want the fields to be enabled at a moment or to stay disabled?

Comment: yes i want the fields to be enabled at a moment. Its like depending on controlling field values, it should enable.

Comment: Can you post your VF page?

Comment: yes sure @MartinLezer

Comment: @Architapatnaik If you are using `<apex:inputField` by default the dependent picklists should be disabled. You don't have to do anything.